# Does ffprobe download the file?

Tags: ffmpeg

When I run `ffprobe http://example.com/abc.mp4` does it download the stream? If it does , will it cleaned up by ffprobe once its done?

Comment: ffprobe only displays information about media files, it won't 'clean up' anything AFAIK. Depending on what, exactly, you mean about cleaning up a file, you may want to use ffmpeg instead (probably with `-c copy`, but that's from me trying to guess what you mean).

Comment: I know ffprobe only displays information, it has to decode the headers of the video to get that information. In this case the video is not locally available, so my question is if ffprobe downloads only part of the video needed to get that information and does it store it locally , if stored will it be removed later?

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely download at least *some* of the stream in order to analyse it. It will not, however, create a file and write that data into it. So there's no cleanup to do.

Comment: Will this be faster and better than downloading the file and running ffprobe on it? Any cons?

Comment: Definitely not worse since ffprobe will only download the part which it needs to identify the codecs. So in the worst case, it will still download the whole stream, but in the best case, only the first few bytes. For the worst case, it might be faster to download the file with a download manager which can do more than one connection, but that's speculation.